# Is it safe to add a big capacitor in parallel to a power supply output?

Tags: power-supply, power, capacitor, current, supercapacitor

I have an application which uses a 1000W standard PC power supply, drawing continuously around 300W. However, sometimes there are short power surges of ~800W or more, which **I believe** triggers the power supply's surge current protection and therefore shuts it down for a while. I was thinking of adding a fairly large (1F) capacitor in parallel to the power supply output, which **I believe** should fix the issue.

However, I am concerned about the capacitor possibly backfeeding current into the power supply. As I understand, under a such a surge, the voltage of the power supply should drop momentarily, which should cause the capacitor to start feeding current into the power supply.

Would this even be a reasonable fix for my issue? Are there any potential issues that could arise from doing this?

Comment: If it's a 1000 watt power supply, why should a moment or two of 800 watts cause the problem you say?

Comment: @Andyaka I honestly don't know. I wasn't expecting this when initially designing the device, as I thought the power supply should be able to handle it, but I guess they are not designed for sudden spikes in current that high?

Comment: The supply might not be rated for that much current on the rail that's being used.  IIRC most ATX power supplies are heavily skewed towards the 5 and 3.3V rails.  The "backfeeding power" issue I wouldn't worry about.  Adding such a large capacitor could cause stability issues though.

Comment: Put a scope on it, measure voltage and current and compare to your design targets and the specs of the supply, Don't apply random fixes until you understand the root cause.

Comment: @vir The power supply has a sticker saying the maximum output for the 12v rail is 980W. No other rails are being used.

Comment: @Andyaka That's because most ATX PSUs struggle to deliver anything close to the nameplate power. It's a vicious cycle of people buying 400W PSUs for office PCs that consume less than 100W on average with spikes below 200W,so manufacturers can get away with designing those PSUs for 200W while labeling them as 400W.

Comment: @vir That's not the case for like 15 years already. Ever since the Pentium 4, CPUs have been powered off the 12V rail,so later versions of the ATX spec kept on progressively lowering the required power on 3.3 and 5V in favour of moving everything to 12V. Many PSUs actually produce 3.3 and 5V using a separate DC-DC stage fed by 12V.

Comment: @TooTea So you believe that the power supply being underpowered is the problem? Even in lover loads of ~150w the same problem occurs.

Comment: Supercapacitors have a very low voltage limit.  You didn't say what this power supply was.  If you over-voltage a supercap, it can fail.  Moreover, if that 1F sits in a 'charged' state because you removed the load, there's a monster store of energy waiting to be released.  If you do this, use a BLEED RESISTOR to draw down the cap when power is removed.   Though ultimately I definitely agree with @Hilmar... Measure the failure first, don't just guess at solutions.

Comment: What's the nature of the load??? Sometimes something simple as a small resistor in series could help (like an ohm or so).   Something to just slow down the current surge a little.  But this assumes, of course, the load won't mind the voltage drop.

Comment: ATX power supplies have multiple rails, each rated at much lower power (i.e. three rails of 300W). Please tell us the model number of your PSU.

Comment: An ohm or two in series for a 25 A (66 A peak) current is not going to end well.

Comment: What is the application you're using this power supply for ? If you're running a motor (table saw, etc) or a lamp from it, the startup surge maybe too high and being treated as a short circuit/surge. In the case of a PC, the board does have some capacitors that will have a surge, but only at startup for a few tens of millisec. Maybe you need a power supply without surge protection but with a fuse (maybe slowblow! ). You can try a capacitor, but see Kyle's warning above. Or can you use a motor starter with resistor ? See http://www.industrial-electronics.com/Motor_Control_5-26.html